# How to know when my MongoDB database overhead reaches its limit?

Tags: mongodb, limit, 32-bit

I installed a MongoDB database on my server. My server is in 32Bit and I can't change it soon.

When you use MongoDB in a 32Bit architecture you have a limit of 2,5Go of data, as mentionned in [this MongoDB blog post](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/137788967/32-bit-limitations).

The thing is that I have several database. So how can I know if I am close or not to this limit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongo will start throwing assertions when you hit the limit.  If you look at the logs, it will have a bunch of error messages (helpfully) telling you to switch to a 64-bit machine.

Using the mongo shell, you can say:

```
> use admin
> db.runCommand({listDatabases : 1})
```

to get a general idea of how close to the limit you are.  Sizes are in bytes.

Comment: Other interesting tools are linked over here BTW:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Monitoring+and+Diagnostics